# How to add path when trying to download file using Response.AddHeader()

Tags: .net

i am not getting how can we add "key value" that i have added in Web.Config file.

this code is not downloading any file:

WebConfig code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName))
            {
                var contentList = db.DataFile.Where(q => q.ID == id && q.FileName.Equals(FileName)).OrderBy(q => q.QID).Select(q => q.TextValue).ToList();

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < contentList.Count; i++)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}", contentList[i]);

                }
                var byteArray = Encoding.Project.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + FileName + "\"");
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);               
                Response.End();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the key Value from web.config you can use this:

```
string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[“AutocoolPath”];
```

Comment: I hope you up it :D @Alin

Comment: Appreciate it :)

Comment: Hi @Alin if you find it helpful my answer kindly up this answer, Thanks!